# Custom UITableViewCell changes when scrolled

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a bar button item which inserts new rows with an incrementing integer variable:

[image]

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var personNo = 0
    var data = [String]()

    @IBAction func addPerson(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        personNo += 1

        tableView.beginUpdates()
        data.append("Person \(personNo)")

        tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: data.count - 1, section: 0)], with: .automatic)

        tableView.endUpdates()

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "newPerson") as! CustomCell

        cell.lblPerson?.text = "Person \(personNo): "

        // Configure the cell...

        return cell
    }
}
```

Adding the rows work, but the cell's value changes when the table view is scrolled:

[image]

Why is this happening and how can I save the state of each cell?

Comment: Use data array for showing the value at cell.lblPerson?.text, personNo contain modified value only. that why you get same value on each cell.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the data from the data source array (`data`)

Replace

```
cell.lblPerson?.text = "Person \(personNo): "
```

with

```
cell.lblPerson?.text = data[indexPath.row]
```

---

Side-note: for your purpose I recommend to use a custom model for example:

```
struct Person {
    var name : String
    var amount : Double
}
```

Comment: It works, but then I will have to append the data with the specific format `"Person 1: "`

Comment: You **do** append data with format "Person 1". If you want unspecified `Person <index>` use  `"Person \(indexPath.row - 1): "`

Comment: I see, is the custom model able to grab the value of the textfield for each rows? I've never used `struct` before but I'll give it a try

Comment: The custom model is a big help but is does not automatically grab the value from the text field. Pass the data source item to the cell in `cellForRow` and update it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You only have a single `personNo` variable, so when cells are generated for scrolling, the current value of `personNo` is used.

You can use the `indexPath.row` value:

```
cell.lblPerson?.text = "Person \(indexPath.row+1): "
```